# json key value javascript : display value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array 'images':

```
images":[{"url":"/uploads/posts/images/1/image.jpg"}]
```

I then did the following to get the path of the first image:

```
var image = JSON.stringify(gon.posts[i].images[0]);
```

However this makes var image:

```
{"url":"/uploads/posts/images/1/image.jpg"}
```

How do I get just the path ie:

```
/uploads/posts/images/1/image.jpg ?
```

I tried image.url but it didn't work.

Comment: JSON.stringify turns your JSON into a string. Instead just do image = gon.posts[i].images[0].url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var obj = {"images":[{"url":"/uploads/posts/images/1/image.jpg"}]};
alert(obj.images[0].url);
```